# codeigniter adding some quotes in query charset issue

Tags: codeigniter, character-encoding

I am tying to join three tables in codeigniter i created query in php myadmin    executed successfully but when i add that query in code

it shows some additional characters in query when printed using

```
enter code here
$this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('kra');
  $this->db->query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
 $this->db->join('users','kra.users_id = users.users_id
 AND users.status="Active"')->join('kra_points',
 'kra.kra_id = kra_points.kra_id 
  AND'." YEAR(kra_application_date) =".'2016'); 
  $this->db->order_by('users_first_name','ASC');
  $this->db->group_by('kra.users_id');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  echo $this->db->last_query();
```

**Query printed on page**

```
enter code here
 SELECT * FROM `kra` JOIN `users` ON `kra`.`users_id` = `users`.`users_id` AND `users`.`status`="Active" JOIN `kra_points` ON `kra`.`kra_id` = `kra_points`.`kra_id` AND `YEAR`(`kra_application_date)` `=2016` GROUP BY  `kra`.`users_id` ORDER BY `users_first_name` ASC
```

**Correct query**

```
enter code here

SELECT * FROM `kra` JOIN `users` ON `kra`.`users_id` = `users`.`users_id`   AND  `users`.`status`="Active" JOIN `kra_points` ON `kra`.`kra_id` = `kra_points`.`kra_id` AND YEAR(`kra_application_date`) = '2016' GROUP BY `kra`.`users_id` ORDER BY `users_first_name` ASC


Why this query is automatically changed i tried solution which is mentioned in other thread  as below but did not worked for me.

Changed char set and dbcollat values in database.php 
'char_set' => 'latin1',
'dbcollat' => 'latin1_swedish_ci',

Request your suggestions here.
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by Code Igniter's automatic escaping mechanism. In order to stop the extra back-tick characters from being included you must send `false` to the optional escape parameter of the offending db query builder function(s).

In the code you've provided the following functions:

- $this->db->select()
- $this->db->join()
- $this->db->order_by()
- $this->db->group_by()

All have optional parameters that default to `null` for escaping data. That tells Code Igniter to escape whatever you send to the function(s). In order to stop that you must send `false` instead.

```
$this->db->select('*', false); // Will stop the select portion from being escaped
$this->db->join('join statement', 'TYPE', false); // Will stop joins from being escaped
$this->db->order_by('order by statement', 'DIRECTION', false); // Will stop order by statements from being escaped
$this->db->group_by('group by statement', false); // Will stop group by statements from being escaped
```